# ¿Cómo doy un espacio entre dos carácteres en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

¡Hola amigos! presento un pequeño problema en mi código JS

Es el siguiente:

```
<label>Telefono</label>
        <span class="pais"><select id="pais">
            <option value="">Seleccione un país</option>
            <option value="+54">Argentina</option>
            <option value="+56">Chile</option>
            <option value="+57">Colombia</option>
            <option value="+52">México</option>
        </select></span>
        <input type="num" id="telf" class="form-control" name="numero" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" required>
```

Y este otro en JavaScript:

```js
function justNumbers(e){
 var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
 if ((keynum == 8) || (keynum == 46))
 return true;
  
 return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
}

var pais = document.getElementById('pais');
var telf = document.getElementById('telf');

pais.onchange = function(e) {
 telf.value = this.value;
 if((this.value).trim() != '') {
  telf.disabled = false;
 } else {
  telf.disabled = true;
 }
}
telf.onkeyup = function(e) {
 var nums_v = this.value.match(/\d+/g);
 if (nums_v != null) {
  this.value = '+'+((nums_v).toString().replace(/\,/, ''));
 } else {
  this.value = pais.value;
 }
}
```

```html
<label>Telefono</label>
   <span class="pais"><select id="pais">
    <option value="">Seleccione un país</option>
    <option value="+54">Argentina</option>
    <option value="+56">Chile</option>
    <option value="+57">Colombia</option>
    <option value="+52">México</option>
   </select></span>
   <input type="num" id="telf" class="form-control" name="numero" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" required>
```

Lo que quiero es que haya un espaciado entre el código de país y el numero que vaya a ser registrado por el usuario. Me explíco: Que el resultado final no quede el código de país junto al numero introducido.

**Como no debe quedar:**

+573193333333

**Como sí debe quedar:**

+57 3193333333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lograr solo necesitas este regex `/(\+\d{2})(\d)/`.

Con ese regex le dices a javascript que busque los 2 primeros 2 números sumandole el símbolo `+`, para después añadirle un espacio para separar el resto del número.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
function justNumbers(e){
    var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
    if ((keynum == 8) || (keynum == 46))
    return true;

    return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
}

var pais = document.getElementById('pais');
var telf = document.getElementById('telf');

pais.onchange = function(e) {
    telf.value = this.value;
    if((this.value).trim() != '') {
        telf.disabled = false;
    } else {
        telf.disabled = true;
    }
}
telf.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var nums_v = this.value.match(/\d+/g);
    if (nums_v != null) {
        this.value = '+'+((nums_v).toString().replace(/\,/, ''));
    } else {
        this.value = pais.value;
    }
        this.value = this.value.replace(/(\+\d{2})(\d)/, '$1 $2');
}
```